Login Screen Appears For a Moment Before Redirecting to Main Screen in Android App
I'm currently developing an Android app using Jetpack Compose. My app has a login screen that uses Firebase Authentication (Google Sign-In). When the user is already logged in, I want the app to directly navigate to the main screen. However, I'm experiencing an issue where, even if the user is already authenticated, the login screen briefly appears for a moment before redirecting to the main screen.
val applicationContext = LocalContext.current.applicationContext
val authClient by lazy {
    EmailAuthClient(
        context = applicationContext
    )
    GoogleAuthClient(
        context = applicationContext,
        authClient = Identity.getSignInClient(applicationContext)
    )
}
val navController = rememberNavController()

NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.LOGIN_SCREEN){
    composable(Screen.LOGIN_SCREEN){
        val signInViewModel = hiltViewModel<SignInViewModel>()
        val state by signInViewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

        // check if already logged in
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
            val user = authClient.getSignedInUser()
            user?.let {
                navController.navigate("${Screen.HOME_SCREEN}/${user.userId}")
            }
        }

        val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
            onResult = { result ->
                if(result.resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    lifecycleScope.launch {
                        val signInResult = authClient.signedInWithIntent(
                            intent = result.data ?: return@launch
                        )
                        signInViewModel.onSignIn(signInResult)
                    }
                }
            }
        )

        LaunchedEffect(key1 = state.isSignInSuccess) {
            if(state.isSignInSuccess){
                val user = authClient.getSignedInUser()
                user?.let {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "Sign in successful",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                    navController.navigate("${Screen.HOME_SCREEN}/${user.userId}")
                    signInViewModel.resetState()
                }
            }
        }

        AuthenticationScreen(
            state = state,
            onGoogleClick = {
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    val signInIntentSender = authClient.signIn()
                    launcher.launch(
                        IntentSenderRequest.Builder(
                            signInIntentSender ?: return@launch
                        ).build()
                    )
                }
            },
          
        )
    }

    composable("${Screen.HOME_SCREEN}/{userId}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument("userId"){ type = NavType.StringType })
    ){ backStackEntry ->

        val userId = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("userId") ?: return@composable
        val notesViewModel = hiltViewModel<NotesViewModel>()

        val onSignOut : () -> Unit = {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                authClient.signOut()
                Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    "Signed out",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
                navController.navigate(Screen.LOGIN_SCREEN)
            }
        }
        HomeScreen(
            navController = navController,
            userId = userId,
            viewModel = notesViewModel,
            userData = authClient.getSignedInUser(),
            onSignOut = onSignOut
        )
    }


I’ve tried placing the authentication check inside a LaunchedEffect and handling the navigation accordingly.
I’ve also set the startdestination dynamically based on whether the user is logged in or not.

replace this:
// check if already logged in
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    val user = authClient.getSignedInUser()
    user?.let {
        navController.navigate("${Screen.HOME_SCREEN}/${user.userId}")
    }
}

with 
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    if(googleAuthUiClient.getSignedInUser() != null) {
        navController.navigate("Home")   //replace with your home screen route
    }
}

ensure that you have getSignedInUser function in googleAuthUiClient
For reference check these 2 links:

https://github.com/007-Shivam/GitHubify/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/shivam/githubify/MainActivity.kt 
https://github.com/007-Shivam/GitHubify/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/shivam/githubify/activity/sign_in/GoogleAuthUiClient.kt

